# How to substitute a random function into a solution of a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, random, hold

I would like to solve a differential equation including a source term.

The source term is a random variable and I model this by creating a list of `RandomReal` and then construct a 1-dim `Interpolation` to get a piecewise linear function.

I then try to replace all the constants appearing in the differential equation as well as the generic input function by values and my linear function.

Unfortunately, this results in a function that includes an **Inactivated Integral** of the **Interpolation**. I don't know, why I can't activate it and wether there is a deeper root of the error, that I don't understand.

````
randomValues = RandomReal[1, 100];
randomInput := Interpolation[randomValues, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[randomInput[x], {x, 1, 100}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Piecewise linear function of random input"]
Print["Trying to solve the differential equation:"]
{U} = {u} /. DSolve[{u'[t] == u[t] + J[t], u[0] == 0}, {u}, t] // 
   FullSimplify // First
Print["Replacing constants and the piecewise Input Function"]
U = U /. {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., C -> 3., R -> 4., J -> randomInput}
Print["There is an inactive Integral involved. Trying to activate it."]
U = Activate[U]

U /@ Range[1, 100] (*List of Unevaluated Functions*)
Plot[U, {x, 1, 100}] (*No Error, but I am suspicious, wether it is the right output now*)
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is better to use `NDSolve` for this. Having to integrate random function is not practical. (after activate, etc...) and will be very slow.

I used the `noise[t]` function from this answer [Continuous noise representation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/continuous-noise-representation) and plugged it as input to the ode. Here is second order ode example using it (you can change the ode to the first order one you had ofcourse).

```
ClearAll[sol, u, t];
tmax = 10;
sigma = 1;
noise = Interpolation[
   Normal[RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[sigma], {0, tmax}]][[1]]];
Plot[noise[t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotLabel -> "Input, white noise"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use NDSolve

```
sol = NDSolve[{u''[t] + u'[t] + u[t] == noise[t], u[0] == 2, 
    u'[0] == 0}, u, {t, 0, tmax}];

Plot[Evaluate[u[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotLabel -> "Solution to ode"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the `noise[t]` to meet your noise specification. This will also work with `DSolve` but I found it very very slow to integrate.

To use `DSolve`

```
sol = Activate[u[t] /. First@ DSolve[{u''[t] + u'[t] + u[t] == 
      noise[t], u[0] == 2, u'[0] == 0}, u[t], t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[sol, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is very slow to plot compared to `NDSolve` plotting since of all the integrals there but if you wait, it will finish.

Comment: Thank you. Nice work-around that also improved the evaluation time. But what was the core problem with the inactive integral? And how would I solve it?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider You just need to `Activate` that is all. But it is slow. Added the code above. The slow part is the plotting, as it has to evaluate the intergals with that noise[t] function in there.