# Stochastic process: Understanding Ornstein Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: plotting, random, stochastic-calculus, random-process, correlation

Recently, I have been trying to simulate a random/stochastic variable that follows Gaussian distribution and also has an exponential correlation function $\left\langle X(t)X(s)\right\rangle= e^{-\frac{|t-s|}{tc}}$. Through many interesting posts from Stack, I realized the function I was looking was the OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess.

Accordingly, I created the following code to simulate my random variable $X(t)$
using a useful post [Continuous noise representation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/continuous-noise-representation?rq=1)

```
ti = 0;
tf = 100;
tc = 1;
dt = .1;

(*analytical correlation*)
corrana[t_]:=CorrelationFunction[OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0,1/10,1/tc],0,t]

(*defining variable*)
X = Interpolation[Normal[RandomFunction[OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1/10, 1/tc],{ti,tf,dt}]][[1]]];

data = Table[X[t], {t, ti, tf, dt}];
{Plot[X[t], {t, ti, tf}], Histogram[data]}

corr = ListPlot[{CorrelationFunction[data, {IntegerPart[tf/dt]}],Table[{t, corrana[t]}, {t, ti, tf, dt}]}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}, PlotLegends -> {"From data", "From model"}, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Correlation"}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}];

Show[corr, PlotRange -> {{0, (3/10)*f/dt}, All}]
```

First, we can see that the histogram presents the Gaussian character of my variable

[image]

Additionally, the plot comparing the numerical and analytical calculation of the correlation function do also match to each other, *but only for small times*.

[image]

Accordingly to those features, I have some questions, namely:

**Question 1:** Why the numerical and analytical correlation functions only present a good aggreement for $t\lesssim tc$? Additionally, it seems there is a *revival* of the correlation for long times, which is evidenced by the oscillations of the numerical correlation functions around the $0$ value. Is this reasonable?

**Question 2:** The axis of the correlation function is not the *real* time but rather the position of the discrete time. How could I plot the numerical correlation as a function of the real time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different x axes. For the correlation function the x axis is 0,1,2,... And for the Table you have 0,0.1,0.2,0.3,...  (Note: f is not defined, I set it to f=0.1)

If we change the x axis of the correlation function to 0,0.1,0.2... we get:

```
corr = ListPlot[{Transpose[{Range[0, tf, dt], 
     CorrelationFunction[data, {IntegerPart[tf/dt]}]}], 
   Table[{t, corrana[t]}, {t, ti, tf, dt}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"From data", "From model"}, Joined -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Correlation"}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}]

Show[corr, PlotRange -> {{0, (3/10)*f/dt}, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 
Do you know how to address my question 2?

Comment: The real time goes from 0..100. And the x axis of the correlation plot goes from 0..100. Does this not answer your question?

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote it wrongly. I was actually referring to Question 1