# Applying NDSolveValue on a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, random, stochastic-calculus, random-process

I am trying to solve stochastic Schrodinger equation (Schrodinger equation in the presence of Ornstein Uhlenbeck Process)
$$i\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}c_1(t)\\ c_2(t)\end{pmatrix}=H(t)\begin{pmatrix}c_1(t)\\ c_2(t)\end{pmatrix},$$

with

$H(t) = \begin{bmatrix} h_1+v t+f(t)- \cos(k) & -i \sin(k)  \\ i \sin(k)  & -h_1-v t-f(t)+\cos(k) \end{bmatrix}$

where $f(t)$ is Ornstein Uhlenbeck Process with noise correlation $\langle f(t)f(t')\rangle=\frac{\xi^2}{2\tau_n}e^{-|t-t'|/\tau_n}$ in which $\xi$ is noise intensity and $\tau_n$ is noise characteristic time.

The parameters $\xi=0.1$, $\tau_n=0.01$, $v=0.1$, $h_1=-50$, $h_2=0.5$, the initial time $t_1=0$ and the final time is $t_2=(h_2-h_1)/v$. The initial values of $c_1(t_1)=1$ and $c_2(t_1)=0$.

I have solved the differential equation using NDSolveValue, and I want to obtain $|c_2(t2)|^2$. My code (please see blow) works. But the results I have obtained is very strange.

Although I have calculated $|c_2(t)|^2$ at $t_2$ for all $k$ and $k$ changes very slowly ($k$ step is very small $dk/\pi=0.001$) but $|c_2(t)|^2$ shows very fast oscillation and very large difference between two nearby $k$ (please see black dots in figure) while the noise is the same for all $k$.

Could you please help me to understand why $|c_2(t)|^2$ shows very fast oscillation. Is my result correct or my code has a problem?

[image]

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
     s_String /; 
       StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
        Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> s <> "`50." &);
Clear["Global`*"];
L = 200;
v = 0.1;
h1 = -50;
h2 = 0.5;
xi = 0.1;
tn = 0.01;

t1 = 0.;

t2 = (h2 - h1)/v;



f = Interpolation[
   Normal[RandomFunction[
      OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, xi/tn, 1/tn, 0], {t1, t2, 0.01}]][[
    1]]];


For[m = 1, m <= L/2, m = m + 1,
  
  
  
  k = ((2 m - 1)*\[Pi])/L;
  
  
  
  {x, y} = 
   NDSolveValue[{I*Derivative[1][c1][t] == 
      2*(h1 + v*t - Cos[k] + f[t])*c1[t] + 2*(-I*Sin[k])*c2[t], 
     I*Derivative[1][c2][t] == 
      2*(I*Sin[k])*c1[t] + 2*(-h1 - v*t + Cos[k] - f[t])*c2[t], 
     c1[t1] == 1, c2[t1] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, t1, t2}];
  
  
  Pk22 = Norm[y[t2]]^2;
  
  Print[k,"       ",Pk22]
  
  
  ];
```

@Daniel Huber @Parsifal Dear Daniel and dear parsifal, I have used your comments [Stochastic process: Understanding Ornstein Uhlenbeck Process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274063/stochastic-process-understanding-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process) , [Continuous noise representation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/continuous-noise-representation?rq=1) to construct the continuous noise function. I think you are expert in this field. I was wondering if you wold be able to let me know you idea and feedback.

Comment: I feel like sharing that I tend to avoid posts that include `$PreRead =...` (unless it's a question about `$PreRead`, perhaps) and ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` or other things that will affect ***my setup***. My eyesight's not that great. It's irritating when I don't notice something like that. I spend time figuring out why things aren't working. Then it turns out because it's because something trashed the state of my session. And the time was spent on something pointless. I don't know how to sandbox ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude of random function `f` you use is too higher compare to 1. With less amplitude we have

```
Clear["Global`*"]; SeedRandom[1234];
L = 200;
v = 0.1;
h1 = -50;
h2 = 0.5;
xi = 0.1;
tn = 0.01;
t1 = 0.;
t2 = (h2 - h1)/v;
f = Interpolation[
   Normal[RandomFunction[
      OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, xi/tn, 1/tn, 0], {t1, t2, 
       0.01}]][[1]]];
eps=1/10;
```

Numerical solution

```
Do[k = ((2 m - 1)*\[Pi])/L;
   {x[m], y[m]} = 
    NDSolveValue[{I*
        c1'[t] == (h1 + v*t - Cos[k] + eps f[t])*c1[t] + (-I*Sin[k])*
         c2[t], I*
        c2'[t] == (I*Sin[k])*c1[t] + (-h1 - v*t + Cos[k] - eps f[t])*
         c2[t], c1[t1] == 1, c2[t1] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, t1, 
      t2}];, {m, 1, L/2}
   ];
```

Visualization

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{((2 m - 1)*\[Pi])/L, Evaluate[Abs[y[m][t2]]^2]}, {m, 1, L/2}],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k", 
   "|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \
\(2\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Could you please let me know why we should consider the amplitude of noise less than 1? As far as I know in the colored noise the amplitude of noise is not restricted and I have considered the amplitude of the noise 1, not very larger than 1. In theoretical calculation the noise intensity $\xi$ and the noise characteristic time $\tau_n$ (noise correlation) are important  and the amplitude of noise does not appear in theoretical calculation.

Comment: We have a deal with numerical computation, and not with theoretical model.  In numerical computation the amplitude of noise should be restricted. Anyway, if you like you can increase `eps` and check what happened with numerical solution.

Comment: Dear Alex, thank yo so much for your instructive and valuable comments.

Comment: @Radmehr You are welcome!